# How to pass -S flag to ocamlopt with ocamlbuild?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I'd like to pass the `-S` flag to ocamlopt when building with the ocamlbuild and corebuild commands.

I understand doing `ocamlbuild -cflag -S ...` won't work since `-S` flag does only exist for ocamlopt and not ocamlc.

How can I do this using _tags files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using *myocamlbuild.ml* and *_tags*.

In *myocamlbuild.ml*, add a `flag` instruction to let ocamlbuild recognize a new tag - here *keep_asm* - which will enable `-S` for selected files when compiling to *native*:

```
flag ["ocaml";"compile";"native";"keep_asm"] (S [A "-S"]);
```

Without the `"native"` string in the list passed to `flag`, the flag would be enabled for any **compilation** stage using **ocaml** (as indicated by the strings `"ocaml"` and `"compile"`), and would trigger when *ocamlc* is invoked, which you don't want.

So, for a complete stand alone *myocamlbuild.ml* doing only the above, this would turn out as:

```
open Ocamlbuild_plugin;;
open Command;;

dispatch begin function
  | Before_rules -> 
    begin
    end
  | After_rules ->
    begin
      flag ["ocaml";"compile";"native";"keep_asm"] (S [ A "-S"]);
    end
  | _ -> ()
end
```

Once, you've got that new tag defined, you may use it in your *_tags* file as with any other tag, for instance:

```
<myfile.ml>: use_bigarray, keep_asm
```